# Adding Custom Metrics rule in Airflow to monitor Airflow-Worker logs via prometheus

Tags: prometheus, grafana, statsd, airflow

I want to monitor my Airflow-Worker logs via Prometheus. Currently I am sending my Airflow-Webserver Metrics available in the official documentation - [Airflow-Metrics-docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/metrics.html) .
So That statsd exporter send these metrics to prometheus to monitor.

Is there any way I can add custom rule so that my Worker logs are monitored by Prometheus as well.

Comment: So do you want to see metrics in premetheus directly without involving statsd ?